# VS2022 Mac can't build, claiming I have missing SDKs

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio-2022

I got a new Macbook for development and I'm now in the process of building the dev environment for it. I have installed .NET 6, 7, and 8  SDKs, then VS2022 and Rider (I mostly rely on Rider and VS2022 is more of a backup and a way to diagnose weirdness, like now).

So, I get some strange error with Rider when I build MAUI apps and wanted to try it with VS2022 to see if I get the same. Instead, turns out, VS2022 can't build any of my projects. When I do I get this:

```
Error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 8.0.  Either target .NET 7.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET 8.0. (NETSDK1045) (TetraPak.XP.Common)
```

For troubleshooting I have made sure .NET 8 is indeed installed...

```
> dotnet --list-sdks
6.0.419 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
7.0.313 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
8.0.201 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

printenv reveals a PATH to the .NET root folder at `/usr/local/share/dotnet`

I have made sure there is no global.json file or Directory.build.props anywhere that points to the wrong SDK

I tried point the environment variable `export MSBuildSDKPath="/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk"`

I ensured VS2022 wasn't building with MSBuild on Mono

I'm now out of ideas. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no support for .NET 8. VS for Mac [was discontinuted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/what-happened-to-vs-for-mac?view=vsmac-2022) and goes out of support in August 2024.

As the announcement says:

> Microsoft doesn't plan to add support for .NET 8 or C#12 to Visual Studio for Mac. We won't extend to any other workloads before retirement either.

The official alternatives are to either work on VS on Windows with a paired Mac, or use VS Code with C# Dev Kit, which requires a subscription similar to Visual Studio. [From the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/cs-dev-kit-faq#_who-can-use-c-dev-kit)

> For personal, academic, and open-source projects, the C# Dev Kit can be used at no cost. For commercial purposes, teams of up to 5 can also use the C# Dev Kit at no cost. For 6+ developers, those users will need a Visual Studio Professional (or higher) subscription. The C# Dev Kit is also included in GitHub Codespaces and Microsoft Dev Box, so users of those products have access to the C# Dev Kit at no additional charge

You *could* use Parallels to run [VS for ARM](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/arm64-visual-studio-is-officially-here/) on [Windows 11 for ARM on a Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/options-for-using-windows-11-with-mac-computers-with-apple-m1-m2-and-m3-chips-cd15fd62-9b34-4b78-b0bc-121baa3c568c). I have no idea if this is a viable option though

Comment: Oh, I had missed that. I did know it would be discontinued this year but wasn't aware .NET 8 wasn't supported. Thanks!

Comment: You can compile from the command line, but I suspect the debug experience with just the C# extension alone won't be that great. Or you could use Parallels to run VS and Windows for ARM on Mac. I have no idea how this will behave though